# Using ArcPy to get point from a cursor for input in arcpy.PolyLine()

Tags: arcpy, cursor, polyline-creation, pointgeometry

I am using ArcGIS Desktop 10.8 Basic. I do not have access to a Standard or Advanced license for this.

I want to use a point from a search cursor as an input for the `arcpy.PolyLine()` method. A second cursor will provide the point feature to be used as the and point of the polyline. My search cursor is on a point feature layer, and I'm using `'SHAPE@'` as one of the fields in the cursor. This is vexing me to no end. In my mind - and this may be my downfall - there's no reason to drill down to the coordinate level.

Isn't it possible to get the geometry for the current cursor's point feature directly?

How do I actually get from two point features in a cursor as inputs for creating a polyline between them?

OR...does the `arcpy.Polyline()` method demand an array of coordinates?

I didn't think it did, but it's hard finding good examples. Nearly all the samples and examples I've found in my searches begin with a set of coordinate tuples, never a point feature from a cursor.

Here's the part of my script that is supposed to do the heavy lifting but doesn't work. Some variables are assigned earlier in the script, but I think you'll see my problems don't involve them. Both cursors are on point feature layers.

```
curfldsAP = ['SHAPE@', 'OID@', fldAPID, fldAPadd]
curfldsGP = ['SHAPE@', 'OID@', "Score", fldGPID]
curNewLine = arcpy.da.InsertCursor(lyrGCline, ['SHAPE@', "FULL_ADDRESS", "ADD_ID"])
with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(lyrAP, curfldsAP) as cur:
    for row in cur:
        linepoints = []
        ptSTART = arcpy.Point(row[0])
        linepoints.append(ptSTART)
        id = row[2]
        add = row[3]
        wc = fldGPID + " = " + str(id)      # whereclause
        with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(lyrGP, curfldsGP, wc) as cur2:
            for row2 in cur2:
                if row2[2] >= 80:
                    ptEND = arcpy.Point(row2[0])
                    linepoints.append(ptEND)
                    newLine = arcpy.Polyline(linepoints)
                    curNewLine.insertRow(newLine, add, id)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's a number of issues here:

- Both row[0] and row2[0] are already `PointGeometry` type objects, for which `.firstPoint` is the `Point` accessor property.
- Use the `arcpy.Array` object to bundle the Points, as in the documentation.
- Never, *never*, **never** use a `Geometry` constructor (`arcpy.PointGeometry`, `arcpy.Polyline`, `arcpy.Polygon`) without the `SpatialReference` of the target feature class in the `spatial_reference` parameter (unless you really want to waste time figuring out how your coordinate precision was truncated after insert/update).
- This task calls for a dictionary cache, not nested cursors.

Manifesting it all looks something like this (not tested):

```py
curfldsAP = ['SHAPE@', 'OID@', fldAPID, fldAPadd]
curfldsGP = ['SHAPE@', 'OID@', "Score", fldGPID]

apCache = {}
with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(lyrAP, curfldsAP) as cursor:
    for row in cursor:
        apCache[row[2]] = { 'point' : row[0].firstPoint, 'oid' : row[1], 'apAdd' :  row[3] }

gpCache = {}
with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(lyrGP, curfldsGP) as cursor:
    for row in cursor:
        gpCache[row[3]] = { 'point' : row[0].firstPoint, 'oid' : row[1], 'score' :  row[2] }

sr = arcpy.Describe(lyrGCline).spatialReference
with arcpy.da.InsertCursor(lyrGCline, ['SHAPE@', "FULL_ADDRESS", "ADD_ID"]) as cursor:
    for apKey in apCache:
        apRec = apCache[apKey]
        gpRec = gpCache[apKey]
        if (gpRec['score'] > 80):
            points = arcpy.Array()
            points.add(apRec['point'])
            points.add(gpRec['point'])
            cursor.insertRow([arcpy.Polyline(points,sr), apRec['apAdd'], apKey])
```

Note that this makes assumptions about 1:1 relationships with keys. If it's 1,M : 0,1,M, the cache needs a different structure.

Comment: Yup, I knew there were issues. Is the spatial reference still necessary if the feature class  that the insert cursor is acting on is in a feature dataset? Much for me to digest with the rest of this. For the record, I did succeed in making this work last night, although I know it can be better.

Comment: Yes, applying the SpatialReference is required, because at the time the Geometry is constructed it doesn't know where the resulting shape will exist.